# How to extract specific/multiple entries from a cell?

Tags: excel

Starting from row 1 to row 2468, I have 3 entries of 16 digit numbers in odd rows in a single cell from which I want to extract the first 16 digit number and place it in a single column. In the even numbered cells, I have two 16 digit numbers and I want to extract both of them to two new columns. Thus I want to have three columns with 1st column being the entry from odd row, and next two columns being entries from the even rows. How to proceed?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30599483/split-cell-by-numbers-within-cell/30600516#30600516

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 formulas. For the formulas below, the data is in column A, the "Odd" case is going in column B, the first "Even" case is in Column C, and the second "Even" case is in column D.

In column B: `=IF(ISEVEN(ROW(A1)),"",LEFT(A1,16))`

In column C: `=IF(ISEVEN(ROW(A1)),LEFT(A1,16),"")`

In column D: `=IF(ISEVEN(ROW(A1)),MID(A1,17,16),"")`  <--this one may need tweaking, depending on how the 16 digit numbers are delimited.

Comment: @ nwhaught: Thanks but I got the problem solved before you posted so didn't try your formula yet.